# Obj-c About Pointers To Functions

Tags: c#, objective-c, function, pointers

I know that blocks can be passed to a instance method and the method can be written as follow,

```
-(void)Method:((void) (^)(float)f)
{
    f(0.5);
}
```

Also, this method is also a valid expression.

```
-(void)Method:((void) (*)(float)f)
{
    f(0.5);
}
```

I want to know that what can i pass to this method? And what is the usage of this?

Besides, I want to know that is there any obj-c equivalent of the following c# code? Because I am wondering that obj-c has function pointer or not.

```
public static float Sum(float x, float y)
{
    return x+y;
}
public delegate float Operation(float x, float y);
public static Main()
{
    Operation dSum = Sum;
    Console.WriteLine(dSum(0.5, 1.5));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second Objective-C method takes a C function pointer whose addressed function has a `float` as input and returns nothing. It's the same as with the block:

```
typedef void (^ BlockType)(float);
- (void)blockMethod: (BlockType)block {
    block(1.0);
}
[obj blockMethod:aBlock];
```

vs.

```
typedef void (* FuncType)(float);
- (void)funcMethod: (FuncType)func {
    func(1.0);
}
[obj funcMethod:aFunc];
```

The difference being that a function cannot capture its surrounding state (and that a function is a function, and a block is a block.)

Comment: I'm new in Obj-C. I would like to know how can I pass a function to instance method? Can you give me an example? I typed the name of a function and the complier told me that I hadn't declared it. Also, What is meant by surrounding state?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require Objective-C; what you're trying to do can be translated pretty easily to straight C:

```
static float sum(float x, float y)
{
    return x + y;
}

typedef float (*Operation)(float x, float y);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Operation dSum = sum;
    printf("%f\n", dSum(0.5, 1.5));
    return 0;
}
```

That should all look pretty recognizable.